# Dealing synchronously in Protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to write what I think is a fairly simple test in protractor, but it would seem that the minute you try to do anything synchronously, Protractor makes life hard for you! Normally, dealing with locator functions (that return a promise) are not an issue, since any expect statement will automatically resolve any promise statement passed to it before testing the assertion. However, what I'm trying to do involves resolving these locator promises before the expect statement so that I can conditionally execute some test logic. Consider (pseudocode):

```
// Imagine I have a number of possible elements on the page
// and I wish to know which are on the page before continuing with a test.

forEach(elementImLookingFor){
  if (elementImLookingFor.isPresent) {
    // record the fact that the element is (or isnt) present
  }
}

// Now do something for the elements that were not found
```

However, in my above example, the 'isPresent' call returns a promise, so can't actually be called in that way. Calling it as a promise (i.e. with a then) means that my forEach block exits before I've recorded if the element is present on the page or not.

I'm drawing a blank about how to go about this, has anyone encountered something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) to do the following;

```
it('element should be present', function(done)
  Promise.cast(elementImLookingFor.isPresent)
    .then(function(present){
      expect(present).toBeTruthy();
    })
    .nodeify(done);
});
```

If you have a few elements that you want to check the `isPresent` on you should be able to do the following;

```
it('check all elements are present', function(done){
  var promises = [element1, element2].map(function(elm){
    return elm.isPresent();
  });

  // wait until all promises resolve
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(presentValues){
      // check that all resolved values is true
      expect(presentValues.every(function(present){
        return present;
      })).toBeTruthy(); 

    })
    .nodeify(done);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that does help a lot, but how can I correllate each resolved promise in promises with it's related element? I assume there is no guarantee they are resolved in order? In your example, presentValues will be an array of true or false values, but I would need to match those values up with the element that isPresent was called on....

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted, thanks for the help. I ended up not using blackbird, but rather the native promise support exposed by protractor (protractor.promise.all rather than Promise.all). I'm also assuming that the promise order is preserved as they are resolved, which seems to be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So `elementImLookingFor` is a promise returned by `element.all`, I presume? Or, as stated in the Protractor documentation, an [ElementArrayFinder](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder). You can call the method `.each()` on it and pass it a function that `expect`s things.

Comment: elementImLookingFor would basically be a protractor ElementFinder, something like element(by.id('myElement1')). My locator varies for each element I'm after, so not sure that ElementArrayFinder works for me in that case.

Comment: But your mention of `forEach` suggests that you want to find multiple elements, for which you should use `element.all`. Or are you using the same code with different locators? Even so you should be able to use `element.all` and iterate over them using `.each()`, which would then only execute the given function once if the locator only matches a single element.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for multiple elements, but each with a very different locator. My 'elementImLookingFor' is just my own internal business object, I need to iterate over the collection to get a property of the object that is used to construct the locator string. @Bulkan has nailed exactly what I need to do (in his example, there is a bit more logic in the map function around creating path string for the locator and such.

Comment: As, I see: you're first collecting a bunch of unrelated elements, and then checking the same property on them (`isPresent`, in this case). In any case, if anybody is Googling the problem I described and find your question, they'll have my answer to help them ^.^