# Should I make Protractor E2E Test completely synchronous

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

**Brief:** Trying to make E2E test in Angular 2 synchronous

Protractor is a wrapper around Jasmine that adds some support for promises in E2E tests, so devs didn't have to create a lot of nested async callbacks, async hell. I presume that Protractor encourages devs to make their tests synchronous.

Quotation from here: https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2015/01/28/angularjs-end-to-end-testing-with-protractor.html

> It is important to note that Protractor is entirely asynchronous, so
>   all API methods return promises. Under the hood, Protractor uses
>   Selenium’s control flow (a queue of pending promises) to allow us to
>   write tests in a pseudo-synchronous way. Protractor is smart enough to
>   make it all work.

This is how people get confused about this.

- [Dealing synchronously in Protractor tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799454/dealing-synchronously-in-protractor-tests)
- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/673#issuecomment-125599377

So, there are still some cases when devs should deal with async methods in their tests, e.g. I need to get **href** attribute of the link and check if it has an ID at the end of it, so I must define callback to get attribute's value, parse it and only after this check if it has an ID or not.

```
$('a').getAttribute("href").then((url) => {
    expect(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'), url.length)).not.toBeNaN();
});
```

As a result, my test is not synchronous and straightforward anymore.

**Question:** Should I move this method from the test to Page Object and try to make it synchronous?

```
// Page Object

getImageId() {

    let attribute = null;
    let link = element(by.css('app-image-container .edit-image a'));

    link.getAttribute('href').then((data) => { attribute = data; });
    browser.wait(() => { return attribute != null; });

    return attribute;
}

// Test is synchronous now

expect(page.getImageId()).not.toBeNaN();
```

Comment: You can await every possible promise. It is more readable than nested `.then`.